# How to check any one array exist while map()?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to print data using array `data` and `data1`.

I have done this

```
{data?.data1?.map((ac1: any) => {
<component prop1={data} prop2={data1}>
 })}
```

this will only work if `data` & `data1` exist. I want to allow with any one must exist.
How to achieve that.

Comment: Please share `data` and `data1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
{!!data.data1.length && data.data1.map((ac1: any) => {
    <component prop1={data} prop2={data1}>
})}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 